# $regularExpression operator in Mongodb not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

When I run the query,

```
db.getCollection('resources').find({
  "owner.firstName": {
    "$regularExpression": {
      "pattern": "^Del",
      "options": "i"
    }
  }
})
```

it shows error mssg,

```
Error: error: {
"ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "unknown operator: $regularExpression",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

Note: Mongodb version is 4.4.0-rc13,This query is derived from,

```
private List<Criteria> buildNameSearch(String type,String name){
        String names[] = name.split(" ");
        ArrayList<Criteria> cr = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
        for (String nm : names) {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where(type+".firstName").regex("^"+nm),
                    Criteria.where(type+".lastName").regex("^"+nm));
            cr.add(criteria);
        }
        return cr;
    }
```

```
Criteria.where(type+".firstName").regex("^"+nm)
```

Please help me with this...

Comment: It should be: `$regex`

Comment: Spring Query ```Criteria.where(type+".firstName").regex("^"+nm)``` returning me with ```$regularExpression``` not ```$regex```

Comment: `$regularExpression` is the [MongoDB Extended Json](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/mongodb-extended-json/index.html#bson.Regular-Expression) which was derived from the spring-data-mongodb code - it is a representation _not_ the actual regex operator. Generally, if you export a collection data to JSON, you will notice that the object fields like date, ObjectId, etc., are shown as extended JSON in the output JSON file (since there is no JSON representation for those BSON types). This is also, similar. The error message is appropriate, and to be expected.

Comment: got it, thanks for helping me with this.

Answer (score 3):

```
db.getCollection('resources').find({
  "owner.firstName": {
      "$regex": "^Del", //regex and pattern goes here
      "$options": "i". //regex options goes here
    }
  }
})
```

1. Use `$regex` instead `$regularExpression` - [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)
2. There is no `pattern`.
3. Use $options

Your spring query looks good.

Comment: Spring Query ```Criteria.where(type+".firstName").regex("^"+nm)``` returning me with ```$regularExpression``` not ```$regex```

Comment: How are you deriving that query?

Comment: I am getting this query from spring logs printing Query, there is no error in spring but in shell

Comment: That's the wrong way of doing. toString ll not provide the exact mongo query.

Comment: I have only provided a part of the  search query from spring logs

Comment: Your understanding is not correct. Taking query from the code is not the correct way of doing it.